# Mouse no longer works

Tags: hardware, mouse, troubleshooting

My mouse was working fine up until this morning. Since then my mouse has stopped working. However the red led bottom is still on and it works in Windows on same machine. The keyboard is unaffected. There is not error messages fired at boot time. What can be the possible reason and how can this be solved.

-- EDIT --

Yesterday I went Out of Space. so I cleared `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`. after some googling I saw few guys in some forum clearing `/var/cache`. So I cleared `/var/cache` too. and everything went nice even after that.
Now on morning Its actually gdm is refusing to take any input (not even keyboard Inputs)
I thought to reinstall gdm. But apt is complaining about missing `/var/cache/apt`

Comment: How is this mouse connected to your PC?  USB, Bluetooth, PS/2, ...?

Comment: Also, did you change something, install something new, install updates before the reboot after which it didn't work anymore, etc.?

Comment: No the Problem lies somewhere else. See Edit Please. I cleared `/var/cache` and probabbly for that reason `gdm` refusing to take any input. `apt` is not working even. What can be done other than copying some else's `/var/cache`.

Comment: I think you will need to rebuild /var/cache. I have tried to fix just apt after removing /var/cache apt and have so far been unsuccessful and had to restore the apt directory manually. You could try t copy this across from the installation CD.

Comment: I've been periodically experiencing this with my USB connected mouse as well. Rebooting usually takes care of it, although if it doesn't (the mouse freezes up again within minutes), Yet Another Reboot almost always does.  Then everything will work fine for days or weeks. This started with 10.04, had never had this particular problem with any prior version.

Comment: The question about the missing /var/cache probably should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure however it might get solved by rebuilding /var/cache.
But You really donno What file to put. Just Copying from others might not solve the problem untill you know the trigger point (e.g. exactly which folder/file is missing there).

I've reinstalled `hal`. and It Started working again. :-)

```
sudo apt-get --purge -remove hal
sudo apt-get install hal
```

However Now I think. just making the following directories manually should work.

```
/var/cache/apt
/var/cache/apt/archives/partial
/var/cache/debconf
/var/cache/gdm
```

*and expecially* `/var/cache/hald`

However I am not still sure whether it will work or not without a `/var/cache/hald/fdi-cache`

and I don't think its possible to make this one manually. unless you copy from others. However I do still have hope that you don't need to create `/var/cache/hald/fdi-cache` manually

Answer (score 0):

Update the BIOS on the computer. I bet you that's where the problem originates from.

Comment: No Man. You lost the bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many USB devices plugged in, they may be underpowered. 
Also there seems to be some (random) bug in modern kernels where a powered usb device confused the kernel and it stops loading up other usb devices.

- Unplug every USB device
- Boot up to the GDM
- Reconnect your keyboard and mouse
- If needed, try them on different USB ports.
- Give it a few seconds

If this solves your problem, go get yourself a powered USB hub. If you already have a powered USB hub, try removing the power to it, during boot, and connecting the power as soon as the GDM is in front of you.